# Types myObj and myObj* are not compatible

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, object

```
class boundaryPt{
public:
friend class KCurvature;
int x;
int y;

boundaryPt(int x, int y){
    this->x = x;
    this->y = y;
}
boundaryPt(){}

};



class KCurvature{
public:
    boundaryPt* boundaryPtAry;
    int numPts;
    ifstream input;

KCurvature(char* inFile){
    input.open(inFile);
    input >> numPts;
    boundaryPtAry = new boundaryPt[numPts];
}

void loadData(char* inFile){
    input.open(inFile);
    int x;
    int y;

    while(!input.eof()){
        input >> x;
        input >> y;
        boundaryPtAry[index++] = new boundaryPt(x,y);
    }
};
```

My issue is with:

```
boundaryPtAry[index++] = new boundaryPt(x,y);
```

I'm trying to store my boundaryPt objects in my array of type boundaryPt, but since I declared that array as boundaryPt* it wont let me a store a boundaryPt.

Is this a simple issue of deferencing a pointer? I'm rusty with C++.

Comment: How about `boundaryPtAry[index].x = x; boundaryPtAry[index].y = y; index++;` ?

Comment: That worked. I realize now that when I create an array of objects, it actually creates the actual objects. So theres no need to even create a new boundaryPt object. Thanks!

Comment: @user5904091 Please post your answer as an answer, instead of updating the question itself.

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED! I realize now that when creating an array of objects, you are not just creating an array, but the objects themselves as well. So there was no need to create a new object and try and put it in the array(or in my case have the array index point to it).

```
while(!input.eof()){
    input >> boundaryPtAry[index].x;
    input >> boundaryPtAry[index].y;
    index++;
}
```

Comment: are you comming from a Java background?

Comment: Short answer: yes.  Long answer: I'm a student and nearly all of my courses have assigned projects in Java until this semester, so I have alot less experience with C++ than java. But I'm happy I learned something new about arrays of objects today.